# How do I prevent the FM radio coming on automatically in a Chevrolet Equinox?

Tags: chevrolet, audio, bluetooth, equinox

I have paired my bluetooth phone with a Chevrolet Equinox. It works well for playing music, etc. I leave the phone paired and playing audio when I park it, shut it off, and walk away.

However, when I turn on the car, it immediately starts playing FM radio. I have to go into this annoying touch screen and manually reselect the Bluetooth audio source.

How can I set the car so that the radio doesn’t turn on by default when it turns on? How can I get it so that it automatically tries to connect back to my phone and play music from it instead of defaulting to FM? FM is very annoying and jarring when first turning on the car and I have to do the same process every time I turn on the car.

Comment: Usually, when you switch off the car stereo manually, it stays off until you turn it on again. When you park the car, remove the key and the stereo switches off automatically, it will switch on automatically the next time you start the car.

Comment: @hobbes even then, how do I turn on the Bluetooth audio when the radio is off without having to listen to FM when switching sources?

Comment: @Hobbes - I think the OP is asking how to stay on Bluetooth rather than it coming back up on FM. They want the radio itself to stay on, they just want it to connect to the phone and continue where they left off at.

Comment: My comment addresses the sentence "How can I set the car so that the radio doesn’t turn on by default when it turns on?" in the third paragraph. The problem may be that the radio switches on, doesn't find the Bluetooth source and then switches to FM.

Comment: Has it always done this? Is this new behavior? Does it do the same thing if you turn off the stereo while still connected (before switching off the car), then after you restart the car, turn on the stereo to see if it reconnects?

Comment: I want the car's audio system to turn on but not turn on the radio where radio means FM input source.

Comment: The car's audio system has always turned on to FM like this. Or if you disconnect your device while it is still on it switches to FM radio. It's really annoying. How do I disable the FM audio source?